# Meanings for the names HAHA and HUHU

Tags: name, gandharva

Haha and Huhu are the names of two sons of Pradha and Kasyapa.

> And it is also known that this Pradha of great fortune, through the
>   celestial Rishi (Kasyapa, her husband), brought forth the sacred of
>   the Apsaras, Alamvusha, Misrakesi, Vidyutparna, Tilottama, Aruna,
>   Rakshita, Rambha, Manorama, Kesini, Suvahu, Surata, Suraja, and Supria
>   were the daughters, and Ativahu and the celebrated **Haha and Huhu**, and
>   Tumvuru were the sons--the best of Gandharvas--of Pradha and Amrita.
>   The Brahmanas, kine, Gandharvas, and Apsaras, were born of Kapila as
>   stated in the Purana.
>
> [[SECTION LXV, Sambhava Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01066.htm)

Most of the names has corresponding meanings. These two names Haha and Huhu seems eccentric. Do they have any special meanings?

Answer (score 1):

Haha and HuHu are two Gadharva  celestial singers  in the assembly of Lord Brahma , who entertains him with divine music. The names of these two are mentioned in many places lik Mahabhrata and Puranas etc.

But the main point in the question is what is the meaning of names of  these two Gandharvas.

## haha हाहा

According to  grammer the word  hāhā (हाहा) mans  .—An interjection of grief, sorrow, or pain. The general word which is realted and well known is hahakara (हाहाकार) which means a grief, lamentation, loud wailing or uproar of battle.

## huhu हूहू

And the huhu means sound of the  burning of fire.

These are general meanings , but this [**article  page**](http://fizikamind.in/%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4-%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AF-%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%AF) is giving us an intresting meaning of these two. According to the page the names haha and Huhu are related swaras and ragas of Indian classical music , and represent  rasa (essence) of Nishadh and Dhaivata ragas. 
here is original hindi narration ,I am translating the passage in english.

> धैवत स्वर का भयानक व करुण रस और हाहा ऋषि है, जबकि निषाद स्वर का शान्त
>   रस और हूहू ऋषि है। पुराणों में हाहा-हूहू ऋषियों में प्रतिस्पर्द्धा
>   चलती रहती है। हाहा-हूहू ऋषि ही परस्पर शाप से गज-ग्राह बनते हैं जिनकी
>   कथा भागवत में प्रसिद्ध है। ऐसा कहा जा सकता है कि हाहा साधना में कोई
>   भयानक रस की स्थिति है जबकि हूहू कोई आनन्द की स्थिति। इस कल्पना की
>   पुष्टि कथाओं से अपेक्षित है।
>
> The terrible or terrifying and tender rasa of Dhaivata raga is rishi
>   HaHa and peaceful rasa of Nishadh swara is HuHu

---

So the two names of Gandharvas HaHa and HuHu are related to music and represent the kind of melodies or rasa  they create i.e. terrifying and tender and peaceful .

Comment: Here is some info.and def. about HaHa and HuHu - https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/haha and https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/huhu